# Title of the papers are not shown in the reference list

Tags: bibtex

I am using a latex template (class) to write my thesis but I get a weird output for the references at the end of the thesis. For instance, if I use something like this in the bib file:

```
@article{hh1952,
  title={A quantitative description of membrane current and its application to conduction and excitation in nerve},
  author={Hodgkin, A.L. and Huxley, A.F.},
  journal={The Journal of Physiology},
  year={1952}
}
```

I get the following output:

[image: reference]

Simply, the title of the papers is not shown but book titles are just fine.

This is all what I found in the template file about bibliography:

```
% Redefine \thebibliography to go to a new page and put an entry in the
% table of contents
\let\@ldthebibliography\thebibliography
\renewcommand{\thebibliography}[1]{%
    \newpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \@ldthebibliography{#1}
}

%\let\@ldbibliography\bibliography
%\renewcommand{\bibliography}[1]{\ifprint@bib\@ldbibliography{#1}\fi}
```

I wonder if it is just a matter of style or it is a bug of the class that I am using? How can I fix the problem?

*Update:*

The `.bbl` file contains the title:

```
\bibitem{hh1952}
A.L. Hodgkin and A.F. Huxley.
\newblock A quantitative description of membrane current and its application to
  conduction and excitation in nerve.
\newblock {\em The Journal of Physiology}, 1952.
```

Comment: What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: @egreg: I cannot find any `\bibliographystyle` command in the file, but have a look at my update.

Comment: You find the bibliography style in the `.aux` file: look for `\bibstyle`. It's probably set in the class.

Comment: The second line of the aux file is: `\bibstyle{rmp2}`

Comment: I found a copy of `rmp2.bst` in the package. You can find a copy of the file here: http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~mroberts/resources/thesis/rmp2.bst

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can see in a [`rmp2.bst` file found in the net](http://ualberta-math-stat-templates.googlecode.com/svn-history/r9/trunk/thesis/rmp2.bst), the style was written for “Reviews of Modern Physics” and it's customary in physics not to mention the article titles in the bibliography.

In my experiment, the result applied to an article is

```
\bibitem[Miglietta {\it et~al.}\ 2012]{miglietta2012detailed}
P.~Miglietta, V.~Fasano, E.~Papadopoulou, B.~Liu, H.~De~Rosa, \& A.~Perrone,
\newblock Physics Procedia, {\bf 32}:335, 2012.
```

without the title. I don't see how your result contains the title which is not printed.

If you're using an official template from your university, you should stick to it.

Comment: Thanks egreg for your answer. Actually, my referees asked me to add the title to my references. Do you have any idea how I can fix the problem? Do I have to change the file `rmp2.bst`?

Comment: @Mohsen There's nothing else to do than changing the bibliography style.